# Detecting if particular string is currently visible on TextField()

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have a TextField() with a quite long text , sometimes last lines are not visible on screen (without scrolling).

Now I want to detect if e.g. word IBM  is currently visible on screen, or is it outside of screen.  Any ideas how to do this?  I want to display this particular word IBM by scrolling myself the textField() to the right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation of the [`getLineIndexOfChar()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/text/TextField.html#getLineIndexOfChar%28%29) to determine the line which contains a given character, then compare the retreived value with [`scrollV`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollV) and [`bottomScrollV`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/text/TextField.html#bottomScrollV) to determine if the given line is visible or not.